# async function expect throw() sinon

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon, throw, sinon-chai

I have class:

```
export class MyClass {

   public async get(name: string): Promise<string> {

     if(name == "test") throw new Error("name is eql 'test'");

    // do something
   }

}
```

I want to check that function get expects throw.

```
expect(myClass.get.bind(parser, "test")).to.throw("name is eql 'test'");
```

But it doesn't work. How do it fix?

Comment: "But it doesn't work." - what does it mean? You get some error? Assertion doesn't pass?

Comment: Throwing in an async function rejects the returned promise. You probably need to test for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use `chai`, chai doesn't support assert error thrown in asynchronous functions. Instead, you can use `try/catch` + `async/await`. An alternative way is to use [chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) plugin.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  public async get(name: string): Promise<string> {
    if (name === 'test') {
      throw new Error("name is eql 'test'");
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('61342139', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    try {
      await myClass.get('test');
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).to.be.instanceOf(Error);
      expect(error.message).to.be.equal("name is eql 'test'");
    }
  });

  it('should pass too', async () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    await expect(myClass.get('test')).to.be.rejectedWith("name is eql 'test'");
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  61342139
    ✓ should pass
    ✓ should pass too


  2 passing (12ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |       50 |     100 |      75 |                   
 index.ts |      75 |       50 |     100 |      75 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```